# Can't make this Pipe & Filter Scala Code to print the output

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, scala-3

I tried multiple approaches but it just not work. this is my code:

```
package assign

import java.nio.file.{Path, Paths}
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{FlowShape, Graph, IOResult, OverflowStrategy}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Balance, Broadcast, FileIO, Flow, GraphDSL, Merge, RunnableGraph, Source}
import akka.stream.alpakka.csv.scaladsl.{CsvParsing, CsvToMap}
import akka.util.ByteString


import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContextExecutor, Future}
import concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import akka.Done
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink

case class DependenciesInfo(groupId: String, artifactId: String, version: String)
case class Record(library: DependenciesInfo, dependency: DependenciesInfo, dependencyType: String) 
case class DependencyCount(library: DependenciesInfo, compileCount: Int, runtimeCount: Int)

object assignment1 extends App:

  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("assignment1")
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = actorSystem.dispatcher

  // Specify Path to CSV File -> Pass as Source -> Source
  val resourcesFolder: String = "src/main/resources"
  val pathCSVFile: Path = Paths.get(s"$resourcesFolder/maven_dependencies.csv")

  val source: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.fromPath(pathCSVFile)

  // CSV Parsing -> Parsed CSV
  val csvParsing: Flow[ByteString, List[ByteString], NotUsed] = CsvParsing.lineScanner()
  
  // CSV Mapping -> Mapped Information
  val mappingHeader: Flow[List[ByteString], Map[String, ByteString], NotUsed] = CsvToMap.toMap()

  // Function to convert a String into DependenciesInfo
  def createDependenciesInfo(str: String): DependenciesInfo = {
    val Array(groupId, artifactId, version) = str.split(":")
    DependenciesInfo(groupId, artifactId, version)
  }

  // Flow to replace string values of keys "library" and "dependency" with DependenciesInfo objects
  val replaceWithDependenciesInfo: Flow[Map[String, ByteString], Map[String, Any], NotUsed] =
    Flow[Map[String, ByteString]].map { inputMap =>
      val updatedMap = inputMap.map { case (key, value) =>
        key -> (key match {
        case "library" => createDependenciesInfo(value.utf8String)
        case "dependency" => createDependenciesInfo(value.utf8String)
        case _ => value.utf8String
      })
      }
      updatedMap
    } 

  val groupedByLibrary: Flow[Map[String, Any], Record, NotUsed] =
    Flow[Map[String, Any]]
      .groupBy(185, record => record("library")) // 185 substreams for unique libraries
      .throttle(10, per = 1.second) // Throttle to 10 groups per second
      .buffer(5, OverflowStrategy.backpressure) // Buffer with capacity 5 and backpressure
      .map { record =>
        val library = record("library").asInstanceOf[DependenciesInfo]
        val dependency = record("dependency").asInstanceOf[DependenciesInfo]
        val dependencyType = record("type").toString // Assuming type is a String

        Record(library, dependency, dependencyType)
      }
      .mergeSubstreams // Merge the substreams back into a single stream
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                                                       //
  //                     ONE TRY                           //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  val countCompile: Flow[Record, Int, NotUsed] =
  Flow[Record].filter(_.dependencyType == "Compile").fold(0)((acc, _) => acc + 1)

  val countRuntime: Flow[Record, Int, NotUsed] =
    Flow[Record].filter(_.dependencyType == "Runtime").fold(0)((acc, _) => acc + 1)

  val instantiateDependencyCount: Flow[Int, DependencyCount, NotUsed] =
    Flow[Int].fold(DependencyCount(DependenciesInfo("", "", ""), 0, 0)) { (acc, count) =>
      DependencyCount(acc.library, count, count)
    }

  val compileCounter: Flow[Record, DependencyCount, NotUsed] =
    Flow[Record].via(countCompile).via(instantiateDependencyCount)

  val runtimeCounter: Flow[Record, DependencyCount, NotUsed] =
    Flow[Record].via(countRuntime).via(instantiateDependencyCount)

  val countDependencyTypes: Flow[Record, DependencyCount, NotUsed] =
    Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val balance = builder.add(Balance[Record](2))
      val merge = builder.add(Merge[DependencyCount](2))

      balance.out(0) ~> compileCounter.async ~> merge.in(0)
      balance.out(1) ~> runtimeCounter.async ~> merge.in(1)
      FlowShape(balance.in, merge.out)
    })

  
  source
    .via(csvParsing)
    .via(mappingHeader)
    .via(replaceWithDependenciesInfo)
    .via(groupedByLibrary)
    .via(countDependencyTypes)
    .to(Sink.foreach[DependencyCount](println)).run()
```

I am trying to implement this architecture:

[image: Application diagram]

It is a Pipe and Filter architecture for a system that processes library dependencies of the Maven repository, i.e., given a dataset of Maven software library dependencies, we want to know how many dependencies each library has.

the end goal is to print an output like this (now I just want the output without formatting):

```
Name: activemq:activemq-core:3.2 --> Compile: 55 Runtime: 96
 and so on ...
```

but now it runs and finish without printing anything. But when I just run it with:

```
source
    .via(csvParsing)
    .via(mappingHeader)
    .via(replaceWithDependenciesInfo)
    .via(groupedByLibrary)
    //.via(countDependencyTypes)
    .to(Sink.foreach[Record](println)).run()
```

it print the output of the `groupedByLibrary` without problem. The output is like this:

```
Record(DependenciesInfo(activemq,activemq-core,3.2),DependenciesInfo(cglib,cglib-full,2.0),Compile)
Record(DependenciesInfo(activemq,activemq-core,3.2),DependenciesInfo(xmlbeans,xmlpublic,2.0.0-beta1),Compile)
Record(DependenciesInfo(activemq,activemq-core,3.2.3),DependenciesInfo(stax,stax-api,1.0),Compile)
Record(DependenciesInfo(activemq,activemq-core,3.2.3),DependenciesInfo(xmlbeans,xbean_xpath,2.0.0-beta1),Compile)
Record(DependenciesInfo(activemq,activemq-core,3.2.3),DependenciesInfo(xmlbeans,xmlpublic,2.0.0-beta1),Compile)
 ... and so on.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it just not work"? Can you provide minimal reproduction case with what you'd expect vs. what you get?

Comment: the end goal is to print an output like this (now I just want the output without formatting):
Name: activemq:activemq-core:3.2 --> Compile: 55 Runtime: 96
 and so on ...
but now it runs and finish without printing anything. But when I just run it with:
```
source
    .via(csvParsing)
    .via(mappingHeader)
    .via(replaceWithDependenciesInfo)
    .via(groupedByLibrary)
    //.via(countDependencyTypes)
    .to(Sink.foreach[Record](println)).run()
```
it print the output of the `groupedByLibrary`

Comment: Mabye the problem is that you do not wait for the stream to finish and hence your main exits before anything is printed? You could try to "await" the result as in [this example from the docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Sink/foreach.html) and see if that helps. (I did not read through all of your code to check for other potential problems, but this one caught my eye immediately.)

Comment: One thing that jumps out is the `Balance` in the `countDependencyTypes` stage, since it's non-deterministic which output it will send an element to.  When combined with different filters between `compileCounter` and `runtimeCounter`, it's possible for a compile dependency to get sent to the runtime path (and get dropped in the filter).  A second thing is that `fold` doesn't emit until the upstream completes, so it might be worth verifying that your source completes.